# Does commit or rollback finish transaction in JPA?

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, commit, rollback

I'm confused here. Does commit or rollback finish transaction in JPA ? I'm using spring and container-managed EntityManager. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: There are actually no other way to "finish" a transaction. Could you explain what you mean by "finish"?

Answer (score 1):

No, the transaction does not end.

Commit will write any unflushed changes to the database and then `commit` in the database.

Rollback will `rollback` in the database.

Comment: Ok, so when transaction is end ? I thought if any exception is throw during transaction so then changes are automatically rollback and transaction is over ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'transaction is over'?

Comment: I mean that transaction is finish so there is no anymore current transaction.

Comment: OK, let me try to put it an other way. The transaction is over in a sense, that it is exactly like you had executed `entityManager.getTransaction().begin();`. On the other hand, transaction is not over, because you do not need to explicitly execute `entityManager.getTransaction().begin();`, you still has a new, empty transaction.

Comment: I found it in Hibernate docs:" Commit does flush the session, but it also ends the unit of work". So it's mean that commit ends transaction (regarding to Your previous answer)